What is the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources.curtin file in Ubuntu 22.04? Can you please explain its purpose, meaning and how to use it?
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04 Server and am noticing a new file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/. The name of the file is ubuntu.sources.curtin. What exactly is this file for, what does it do, how do I use it, and can I delete it?
According to apt, it seems to have duplicate repositories in it. Can I delete it? Or what should I do with this file? What is the meaning of it in Ubuntu 24.04?

I'd expect that to be a file leftover from the installation process - did the installation crash? Apt should be ignoring it, what's the actual error message you get?

Find out which package provided it with dpkg -S /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources.curtin . See what other files (README, other documentation,  helper programs) with dpkg -L  followed by the package name.

ubuntu.sources.curtin is a leftover from the installer on some Ubuntu 24.04 installations. It is a potential installation bug. It might contain duplicate entries of repositories that are already present in the standard sources.list file.
You can either safely delete the ubuntu.sources.curtin file with sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources.curtin or make it into an inactive backup file by running the following command.
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources.curtin /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources.curtin.bak

The inactive ubuntu.sources.curtin.bak backup file will not generate any messages when running sudo apt update or sudo apt upgrade.
